Rate Limits with Cloudflare Workers
I’m using a CF Worker to make batch UPDATE requests to a third party API using fetch along with Promise.all
The third party API endpoint has a rate limit of 60 requests/minute. Rate limit info is returned on each request with headers X-RateLimit-Remaining and X-RateLimit-Limit
The third party endpoint requires an access token to be sent along with the request, but I’m assuming that rate limiting is based on IP address (of the worker in this case).
Which leads to my question - if I have multiple users of my (small) app all making batch requests, I would quickly run into rate limit errors if 2 users (or even 1) send a that batch request.
My questions:
How will the third party API receive requests from my CF workers if two users send at same time? Will it depend on region used? Should I assume the requests will come from same IP or different IP address?
How should I think about limiting how many requests are allowed per batch, given the third party rate limit of 60 requests/minute? I was hoping to do 100 concurrent requests but that obviously won’t work now. Maybe 10?
How do large production apps handle integrations with third parties like this? Do they get higher rate limits for their servers?
I was hoping to give my users an button to “Update All” but I am instead forced to rework the UI/UX to allow the user to check off 10 items max and then click an “Update these 10 items” button. Something like that.
Thank you!

Are you sure the limit is not for apikeys?
